# Treeview with Grid inside in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to display a simple schema of a database in a treeview with 1 level of depth.
So I have a collection of tables, whose name I'd like to display as a header of the elements, and for each table a collection of columns with name, type, etc..

However in each table I want to display those columns definition in a grid, with a header specifying the properties of the columns definition, and in each row, the definition itself.

One way to make this work is to see that as a treeview where **each table** has a **sequence** of **one child** (the entire collection of column definition), then displayed as a grid :

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" x:Name="treeView"  MinWidth="400" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListofONEelement}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TableName}" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupOfColumnDefinition}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Model"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.Model}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnStatus" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.ColumnStatus}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnType"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.ColumnType}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

But I had to create this intermediate structure  `ListofONEelement` to make this works, as hierarchy in the treeview exists only if there are items to enumerate.

Are there other, nicer ways to do this, **directly in XAML**, that would not require to have a custom type created in my ViewModel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually put the one item in the TreeView. Don't use HierarchicalDataTemplate.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding TableName}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupOfColumnDefinition}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Model"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.Model}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnStatus" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.ColumnStatus}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnType"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2.ColumnType}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: and how do you bind it to the first level collection (the tables)  ? when I specify both a itemsSource and a TreeViewItem, my xaml crashes, it cant handle 2 sources .

Comment: Ok. So I've finally got this to work. This is how you need to set it up if you want to avoid using your ListofOneElement class.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much, I am slowly getting it and was able to  remove another superfluous structure with this.